# Destructure an array parameter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Is it possible to destructure a function parameter?

For example, I would want to convert this:

```
Object.entries({}).find(group=> group[0] === "foo" && group[1] === "bar");
```

To something like this:

```
Object.entries({}).find([0: key, 1: value] => key === "foo" && value === "bar");
```

or

```
Object.entries({}).find([...key, value] => key === "foo" && value === "bar");
```

Comment: Try `.find(([ key, value ]) =>` - note the extra parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that to destruct the arrow function parameters you should do `([key, value])`

Code:

```js
const obj = {
  asdf: 'asdf',
  foo: 'bar'
};

const result = Object
  .entries(obj)
  .find(([key, value]) => key === 'foo' && value === 'bar');
  
console.log(result);
```